# Updating entire collection in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection with various documents in it. Every tot seconds my Python scripts retrieves some data from an API, i want to update each document of the collection with the updated version of the document, so the entire collection has to be updated.

```
result = db.main_tst.insert_one(dic)
```

This is how i insert the data. Now instead of inserting `dic`, i should update it. How can i do it with Python in MongoDB? I know there is the `update_many()` method, but i've only found how to update a certain document, instead of the entire collection.

Comment: what do you've in dic ? Is that entire document or a field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be simple :

Let's suppose if you consider below, it would update all matching documents where field name = 'N/A' to "No name" :

```
filterQuery = { 'name': 'N/A'}
updateQuery = { "$set": { "name": "No name" } }

result = mycol.update_many(filterQuery, updateQuery);
```

Where as for your requirement as you need to update all documents in a collection, all you've to do is pass empty `{}` in place of filter, means it should update all documents :

```
filterQuery = {}
updateQuery = { "$set": { "name": "No name" } }

result = mycol.update_many(filterQuery, updateQuery)
```

Comment: Thank you! If i already have a dictionary to use, should i just do "$set": dic?

Comment: Hey, just one thing: if i use update_many() each document of the collection will be updated, but they will all have the same value. I tried to use update_one() instead, but it does not update any record

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm confused of !! Can you give me what do you've in dic ? I mean sample data, I was about to ask you the same, to check whether this is your req or not..Does Dic has few documents with entire data of those documents ? Do you've any unique field for that document to search against collection and update or insert if it's not already there in the collection ...

Comment: The data i'm updating is just a normal dict that looks like this {"item": "some item", "price": 99, "test": "test"}

Comment: @Jack022 : Yes with the answer above the same will be updated or added to all documents in collection, then here what exactly you're looking for ? let's say each document in your collection has to have different data in those fields, then is there a unique value to filter certain documents/document to update those/that with new data, I certainly write a query to satisfy that requirement.

Comment: I think i should open a new question for this, since the problem is another. Basically i'm retrieving data from an API. For each json in the api, a new document is created. Every tot seconds the script should update all the records with the new ones received by the api, the new problem now is that it updates all the records with the same value, instead of updating each record with a new value retrieved

Comment: @Jack022 : Ok that should be good, raise a new question with sample data & sample response & ping link here, I can help if I'm able to.. Meanwhile to be simple if you get a set of dictionaries which needs to be updated in collection for respective documents you can use update_one with a filter (filter is unique field value)